# better way to put text beside a toggle button

Tags: html, css

im new to coding this my second code practice on frontend mentor (https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/pricing-component-with-toggle-8vPwRMIC) I want to position "annually" next to the toggle button,
I used :before and position relative to push the text to the desired position. Is there a better and cleaner way to code it? i have tried searching google for similar problem but i did not found any code that worked for me.

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: hsl(236, 72%, 79%);
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.toggle:before {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  content: "";
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

input:checked+.toggle:before {
  transform: translateX(30px);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  left: 10px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label::before {
  content: "Annually";
  position: relative;
  right: 90px;
  top: 5px;
}

div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Our Pricing</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="box">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="toggle"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="c1">
</div>
<div class="c2">
</div>
<div class="c3">
</div>
```

Comment: pls explain more.. we can't understand

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to predict without live example, how Your code is behave, but generally you don't have to use `:before` pseudoclass to make this effect. If You are already using flexbox on wrapper, just add the labels in some spans, maybe something like this:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
      <span>Annually</span>
      <label class="box">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <span class="toggle"></span>
      </label>
      <span>Monthly</span>
  </div>
```

Add `flex-direction: row;` to have all elements in wrapper go in the horizontal flow:

```
div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code snippet, Use 'margin-left: -80px' to offset the position.

```
    label::before {
      content: "Annually";
      margin-left: -80px;
      line-height: 30px;
    }
```

```css
.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: hsl(236, 72%, 79%);
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.toggle:before {
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  content: "";
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 24px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}

input:checked+.toggle:before {
  transform: translateX(30px);
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  left: 10px;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label::before {
  content: "Annually";
  margin-left: -80px;
  line-height: 30px;
}

div.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>Our Pricing</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <label class="box">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="toggle"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```